# How can I write a function that adds an object to a class?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, garbage-collection

I want to add an object to a class with a function.
This is what I have tried but the output was not what I expected at all.

```
import gc

class People:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

example = People('example')

def adding():
    firstName = input('First name:')
    lastName = input('LastName:')
    fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
    fullName = People(fullName)
    addMore = input('Add another one?')
    if addMore != 'no':
        adding()

    for obj in gc.get_objects():
        if isinstance(obj, People):
            print(obj.name)

adding()

print(10*'=')

for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if isinstance(obj, People):
        print(obj.name)
```

So what I have tried is to create a simple class and create an adding function.
I also have some code that is meant to print all objects in my class. That code is executed twice: once at the end within the adding function and once at the end of all of the code. I printed a line between the two to distinguish them.

I executed the code and used the adding function to add 5 names: Alex Alberts, Brian Borne, Casey Connor, Donna Dawson and Emma Edwards. This is the result:

```
example
Alex Alberts
Brian Borne
Casey Connor
Donna Dawson
Emma Edwards
example
Alex Alberts
Brian Borne
Casey Connor
Donna Dawson
example
Alex Alberts
Brian Borne
Casey Connor
example
Alex Alberts
Brian Borne
example
Alex Alberts
==========
example
```

I am not sure why the objects seem to be disappearing and why the adding function prints the names with that pattern. I expected and I wanted the code to print the example object and all names I entered only once. And I wanted the adding function and the code at the end to print the same object names.

I am sorry if I did not explain all of this clearly.

Comment: Your `adding()` function has a recursion. This explains the unexpected pattern. So, when you perform `adding('Alex Alberts')`, you call `adding('Brian Borne')`, and so on. Once all the inputs are completed, all the stacked up `get_objects()` loops belonging to the last `adding()` call all the way thru the first `adding()` call are executed one by one. This stacking is causing that pattern. So, in this case, you must avoid recursion.

Comment: The above comment is correct. In addition to the problem being caused by the suspect recursive loop, using `gc` in this way is not a very good idea- there are much better and less fragile ways.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing something more like this instead of mucking around with the `gc` module. Using the global namespace to hold your objects isn't effective, is hard to read later when you have been away from the code a while, and is very unreliable.

Place your objects inside of a built-in python data structure instead, like a `list`. This way, you know exactly were they all are and don't have to go "looking" for them in `gc.get_objects()`, or `locals()`, or `globals()`.

```
class People:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

example = People('example')

def make_person():
    '''A person factory.'''
    firstName = input('First name:')
    lastName = input('LastName:')
    fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
    person = People(fullName)
    return person

def add_people(p_list, addMore='yes'):
    '''Adds people to a list.
    addMore is given the value of 'yes' by default
    in order to get the loop started. 
    '''
    while addMore == 'yes':
        p = make_person()
        p_list.append(p)
        addMore = input('Add another one?')

person_list = list() #  an empty list to hold all the people

add_people(person_list)

print(10*'=')

for obj in person_list:
    print(obj.name)
```